# Advanced slider, which show width between two indicators

Tags: javascript, windows, slider, exe

Yesterday I had an idea to help myself at work.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH8gK.png)
What's going on?
I have an input value and a number of thumbs.
Input: 1400
Thumbs: 5
Section lengths: 20, 50, 100, 110, 130, 150, 260, 320, 340, 360, 380, 400, 420, 450, 500
I want to move my thumbs (left and right) to use the widths above and their sum is 1400.

I have no idea how to do it. Maybe you can help? Thank you

I was trying modify range slider from example source. No effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.